# Blazor client + Keycloak error: blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, cors, blazor, keycloak

Sorry, I tried many solutions to configure correctly the keycloak version 21, but I don´t know why I still see this error, for exemple:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/arqgrifo/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'https://localhost:44337' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and in my keycloak client app settings, I have
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KeyCloak : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018604/keycloak-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r)

Comment: Hi, It did not worked for me. I still have the same error

Comment: Is your keycloak or your client hosted in an IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if your keycloak or your client is hosted in an IIS that *HTTP Response Headers* is not set to add a *CORS policy*-header.
I.E. remove any added CORS policy in your IIS manager under *HTTP Response Headers*.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In new keycloak version, we don´t use the url with "auth", so deleting this word of the url everything works